# How to make an EditText Box in android?

Tags: android

I would like to make my application ask the user some informations via something similar to VB.NET's inputbox. How can I do this??? I don't want to have a permanent control on the screen, I just want to make it appear when I need it. Actually, just as an inputbox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This link will show how to use EditText:

http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-user-interface-design-edittext-controls/

Answer (score 0):

Use an edittext box, very similar to a textview. examples can be easily found